# Close other div when new is clicked

Tags: javascript

So I have this table with a menu dropdown, but I'm having trouble getting the divs close when I click on one of the other menu dropdown divs. This is because the JS looks for a click inside/outside of the class, but how can I change this?

I'm trying to avoid the user from opening multiple dropdown menus at the same time, like this:

[image: img]

Here is the working code to see the problem.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function wdc_jql_menu(menu_id) {
    document.getElementById(menu_id).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.wdc_jql_table{
    /* table width */
    border:1;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    table-layout:fixed; // Cells is fixed to the percentage the cells is assigned too
    word-wrap:break-word;
    color: white;
}

.wdc_jql_table thead, tr{
    /* table style - bottom borders to seperate rows */
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #3A3B41;
}
.wdc_jql_table tr:last-child{
    /* table style - no border at last row */
    border-bottom: none;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2), 
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4){
    /* table child th align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2), 
td:nth-child(3){
    /* table child td align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wdc_jql_table
td:nth-child(4){
    /* table child td align (...) */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.wdc_jql_col1{
    /* table col(project name) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col2{
    /* table col(owner) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col3{
    /* table col(jql) width */
    width: 50%;
}

.wdc_jql_col4{
    /* table col(...) width */
    width: 10%;
}

/* MENU DESIGN */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #8D90A1;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<table id="others_jql" class="wdc_jql_table padding_jql_bottom">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col1">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col2">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col3">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col4">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>JQL</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody id="table_body_others">
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td1</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td2</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td3</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_1')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_1" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_2')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_2" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_3')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_3" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the solution is to rewrite the JS to listen for the div ID and then close the other open/shown classes I guess, but how?

Comment: Please replace the php cody by html data. The internal snippet editor does not support php.

Comment: Either _find_ the element that currently has the class `show` and then remove that class, before you set it for the current one; or _remember_ what element you added the class to the previous time, and then remove it from that.

Comment: An easy approach is to remove all occurences of class `show` and add this class only for clicked element.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that works! just removed the `window.onclick` and now I removed all `shown` before I view the clicked one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment

`Either find the element that currently has the class show and then remove that class, before you set it for the current one; or remember what element you added the class to the previous time, and then remove it from that. –  CBroe`

the solution was created here:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function wdc_jql_menu(menu_id) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(menu_id).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.wdc_jql_table{
    /* table width */
    border:1;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    table-layout:fixed; // Cells is fixed to the percentage the cells is assigned too
    word-wrap:break-word;
    color: white;
}

.wdc_jql_table thead, tr{
    /* table style - bottom borders to seperate rows */
    border-bottom: 1.5px solid #3A3B41;
}
.wdc_jql_table tr:last-child{
    /* table style - no border at last row */
    border-bottom: none;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
th:nth-child(1),
th:nth-child(2), 
th:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(4){
    /* table child th align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wdc_jql_table 
td:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(2), 
td:nth-child(3){
    /* table child td align (project name, owner, jql) */
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wdc_jql_table
td:nth-child(4){
    /* table child td align (...) */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.wdc_jql_col1{
    /* table col(project name) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col2{
    /* table col(owner) width */
    width: 20%;
}

.wdc_jql_col3{
    /* table col(jql) width */
    width: 50%;
}

.wdc_jql_col4{
    /* table col(...) width */
    width: 10%;
}

/* MENU DESIGN */

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #2F2F35;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #8D90A1;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<table id="others_jql" class="wdc_jql_table padding_jql_bottom">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col1">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col2">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col3">
    <col class="wdc_jql_col4">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Owner</th>
          <th>JQL</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody id="table_body_others">
        <tr id="tr1">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td1</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td2</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td3</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_1')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_1" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_2')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_2" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr3">
            <td name="projectNameTable">td11</td>
            <td name="employeeNo">td22</td>
            <td name="jqlTable">td33</td>
            <td name="edit_personal"><button onclick="wdc_jql_menu('menu_3')" class="dropbtn">&#8942;</button>
            <div id="menu_3" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#Remove">Remove</a>
            </div>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello just tried below code and worked,

```
   /* When the user clicks on the button, 
   toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
   function wdc_jql_menu(menu_id) {
      clearDropdown();
      document.getElementById(menu_id).classList.toggle("show");
   }     

   // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
         clearDropdown();
      }
   }

   function clearDropdown() {
      const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
      boxes.forEach(box => {
         box.classList.remove('show');
      });
   }
```